# What is the meaning of python interpreter (by conda) in pycharm project which creates virtual environment

Tags: python, pycharm, virtual-environment

I once created an anaconda environment. Now I have just started using pycharm. Whenever I create a new project it automatically creates a new virtual environment. Then it asks for python interpreter. It shows the option to select from the environments I created on conda.

I wanted to know whether pycharm is using the packages installed on conda environment on my pycharm environment or  creating a copy of the packages from conda environment to the pycharm environment? 
P.S- I am new to python so it would be helpful if you point out any technical mistake in my question and help me to improve.

Comment: virtual environments typically have their own packages ... however you can make global site packages available with the checkbox when creating a new virtual environment ... or you can use the any existing interpreter ,,, and it just uses that interpretter